# Sorting array that can and cannot be divisible into a certain number

Tags: c

i have to do.
instruction:
Write a C program which reads a number n from the user and in decreasing order
prints the numbers between 1 and n (included) that are divided by 3 and at the same time
are not divided by 2 and 5. Print also their summation.
if n is 100
expected output:
[image]

```
int main(void)
{
  int i, j;
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &i);

  for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
    if (j % 3 == 0)
    if (j % 2 != 0)
    if (j % 5 != 0)
    printf("%d ", j);

  return 0;
}
```

i have to sum all of them.

Comment: Start by writing a program that reads a number from the user, and then prints the number.

Comment: Just do it one small and simple step at a time.

Comment: Sorting...? It seems you should just iterate in decreasing order.

Comment: And there's really no need for an array, only iteration (as mentioned by @MikeCAT).

Comment: i have to use something like this for descending for(j = i; j > 0; j--)

Comment: Take input from user in any order store values in array (keep track of how many are stored). Sort array descending (with `qsort`). Iterate over each value and output/sum values where  `%3 == 0` and NOT `%5 == 0` and NOT `%2 == 0`.

Comment: @nashere Yes, that's correct, but first you need to read `i` from the user.

Comment: i did it like this, and i have to solve the division
int main(void)
{
  int i, j;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &i);

  for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
      printf("%d ", j);

  return 0;
}

Comment: If you are guaranteed the user only enters values in descending order of value -- then there is no need to sort (though the correct operation of your code will then rely on the behavior of the user -- not very robust code) You are thinking in the right direction, but your test needs to be `if (arr[i] % 3 == 0 && arr[i] % 2 && arr[i] % 5)`

Comment: `int main(void)
{
  int i, j;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &i);

  for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
    if (j % 3 == 0 && j % 2 == 0 && j % 5 == 0)
    printf("%d ", j);

  return 0;
}
`
i cant create Not condition

Comment: Sure you can. Just change the `== 0` for `%2` and `%5` to `!= 0`. You need to keep track of the number of values the user enters.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The user only enters one number: `n`

Comment: That makes it even easier. You don't have to keep track then `:)`

Comment: @nashere You should [edit] the question, and show any code that you have in the question itself.

Comment: i did do you suggest any help

Comment: You still don't have `if (j % 3 == 0 && j % 2 && j % 5)` and where are you keeping track of the `sum`? You also need to check the return of `scanf`, e.g. `if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer.\n", stderr); return 1; }` to validate your input. (you cannot use any input function correctly without checking the return). Also, unless you are handling negative value for `i`, you need to check that `i > 0` -- otherwise your loop will be very very short.

Comment: What if you add `long sum = 0;` up top, then in your loop as it is written do: `if (j % 5 != 0) { printf("%d ", j); sum += j; }`? Then after the loop just `printf ("\n\nthe sum is: %ld\n", sum);`?

Comment: it's great it is work. But they start print the "0" with `printf("%d ", j);`.It mustn't. How can be fix ?

Comment: like this [IMAGE](https://imgur.com/VygEtjD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code produces the correct output, but does not compute the sum.

It is easy to do this: add a variable `sum` initialized to `0` and increment it by the numbers that you print.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    long sum = 0; // use type long to avoid overflow on large values.
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &i) == 1) {
        for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (j % 3 == 0) {
                if (j % 2 != 0) {
                    if (j % 5 != 0) {
                        printf("%d ", j);
                        sum += j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n\nthe sum is %ld\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 100
99 93 87 81 69 63 57 51 39 33 27 21 9 3

the sum is 732
```

Note that the nested `if` statements can be combined into a single test expression:

```
    if (j % 3 == 0 && j % 2 != 0 && j % 5 != 0)
```

Here is a more obscure version with a single modulo operator per iteration and a lot less of them:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    long sum = 0; // use type long to avoid overflow on large values.
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &i) == 1) {
        for (j = i / 3; j > 0; j--) {
            if (650 >> j % 10 & 1) {
                printf("%d ", j * 3);
                sum += j * 3;
            }
        }
        printf("\n\nthe sum is %ld\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain how the effectively obscure version comes from ?

Comment: @bruno: 650 is `512+128+8+2`, ie: `(1<<9) | (1 << 7) | (1 << 3) | (1 << 1)`. The operator precedence helps with obfuscation: the expression is parsed as `(650 >> (j % 10)) & 1`. It tests if `j % 10` is one of `1 3 7 9`. The loop enumerates multiples of 3 that are not multiples of 2 nor 5, from `i / 3` down to `3`.

Comment: that recalls me something now, I think you already did a similar answer in past, isn't it ?

Comment: @bruno: yes it is a useful pattern to test if a number known to be in a small range is a in a set in a single test without a memory access. The test can also be written `if (650 & 1 << j % 10)`

Answer (score 0):

my code works thanks for the all answers. i promise i will try harder before ask a question. Thanks for every little help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int i, j;
  long sum = 0;
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &i);

  for(j =i; j >0; j--)
    if (j % 3 == 0)
    if (j % 2 != 0)
    if (j % 5 != 0)
    {
    printf("%d ", j);sum += j;
    }
    printf ("\n\nthe sum is: %ld\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is badly mis-indented. Please spend some time improving the presentation, it helps prevent bugs, allows other programmers to read and understand your code and sooner or later, the next reader will be yourself.

Comment: yes your are right. i will do that with your sample

Answer (score -2):

hey look at this code may help you

int main(void){int i, j;printf("Enter a number: ");scanf("%d", &i);for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
    if (j % 3 == 0 || j % 2 != 0|| j % 5 != 0) printf("%d", j);
  return 0;}

Comment: Unlike the OP's, your code does not output the expected numbers and neither does it compute the sum.

Comment: out of that by pity when you give code use several lines and indent them, @chqrlie had courage to read it